# Adding flags to Highstock chart (highcharts) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I've been working on this demo chart http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/G7rsh/ and I'm struggling to add flags to the x axis.

In the examples on the highchart webpage they use UTC to locate the flag, however the series on this chart are plotted in a different way, using this format [1330560000000,32.29]

Would anybody have an answer? I'm not sure if this is specific to JavaScript or Highcharts but thought it would be worthwhile posting on here.

I've tried adding

`series: [{
                type: 'flags',
                data : [{'text':'Flag Set','title':'E','x':1330560000000} ],
                width: 16
            }],`

to the javascript but this doesn't seem to do anything, any help would be amazing, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
    selectSeries(0);
    // build flags
    seriesOptions.push({
        'type': 'flags',
        //'name': 'myflag',
        'data': [{
            'title':'E',
            'x':1330560000000
        }],
        'width': 16,
        // if you want to place to some serie add the following line
        //'onSeries': 1 //serie id
    });
    createChart();
}
```

You can see the following [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/G7rsh/4/).

Answer (score 1):

this is unix time format , when working with highstock you have to use unix time format to represent the xaxis

*this is how you add flags to highstock*

```
         var alarms = { type: 'flags', name:'flag',color: 'red',
              data : 
              [{x:1326845030000,title : 'Alarm 1',text : 'Alarm 1'} ,                                                             
               {x:1326847030000,title : 'Alarm 2',text : 'Alarm 3'} , 
               {x:1326840030000,title : 'Alarm 3',text : 'Alarm 2'} ],
                shape : 'squarepin',width : 50  };
```

`alarm` variable will then be pushed to your series array

`x` is where you will place your flag on the xAxis , if you want your flag on a series , use `onSeries : 'series_id'` object in the alarm object

Comment: this sounds good! sorry for my complete ignorance but looking at my jsfiddle whereabouts would I put this?

Comment: there is something wrong with the jsfiddle it doesn't load to my browser just tell me where would you like to add the flags

Comment: the position of the flags doesn't matter at the moment, i've tried adding that code to the javascript and it's not working, what's not working in the jsfiddle? I can post the code here if that's easier?